flutter column + expanded widget display strangely in android, it is normal in ios
at first expanded doesn't work, the black block is on the center, but after few seconds it display normally, the black block display on the bottom. it's strangely.
if you know the reason, please tell me, thank you very much.
enviroment: android 13 / flutter 3.19.6.
class RegistrationInfoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegistrationInfoPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _RegistrationInfoPageState();
}

class _RegistrationInfoPageState extends State<RegistrationInfoPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Text('index')),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.black,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

it's come from
Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegistrationInfoPage()));


I hope that the black block is only display on the buttom, no intermediate action.

The code you have shared is perfect, and it should work. Do you have any other code in that file that you can share?

I have added some code, which part do you think  maybe have problem?

How is RegistrationInfoPage used? Maybe there's a mistake in its parent

@Ivo you are right, parent page display the input board, if not closed, child page will ocurr this using MediaQuery.Sizeof(), thank you very much.

parent page display the input keyboard, if not closed, child page will ocurr this.
class RegistrationInfoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegistrationInfoPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _RegistrationInfoPageState();
}

class _RegistrationInfoPageState extends State<RegistrationInfoPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // avoid to repaint because of computing the keyboard's height
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Text('index')),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.black,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

